# Attempt to invoke virtual method Activity_Animation002_Layout.resume() on a null object reference

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas

This is the error, I am trying to do as the tutorial in Youtube but it's not working. I am learning Canvas, draw path , circle and bitmap image.I don't even know why it must run in the thread, I understand that the problem is

```
public void resume(){
        CanDraw = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
```

but I have no idea how to fix it.
The error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: examples.com.testdraw, PID: 10253
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {examples.com.testdraw/examples.com.testdraw.AnimationActivity002}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   examples.com.testdraw.Activity_Animation002_Layout.resume()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   examples.com.testdraw.Activity_Animation002_Layout.resume()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                              at
>   examples.com.testdraw.AnimationActivity002.onResume(AnimationActivity002.java:30)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)

AnimationActivity002

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

/**
 * Created by lam on 7/8/2016.
 */
public class AnimationActivity002 extends Activity {
    Activity_Animation002_Layout animation002_LayoutView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        animation002_LayoutView = new Activity_Animation002_Layout(this);
        setContentView(animation002_LayoutView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        animation002_LayoutView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        animation002_LayoutView.resume();
    }
}
```

Activity_Animation002_Layout

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * Created by lam on 7/8/2016.
 */
public class Activity_Animation002_Layout extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread thread = null;
    boolean CanDraw = false;

    Bitmap backGroundCheck;
    Canvas canvas;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;


    public Activity_Animation002_Layout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        backGroundCheck = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (CanDraw){
            if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }

            canvas =surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(backGroundCheck,0,0,null);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void pause(){
        CanDraw =false;
        while (true){
            try {
                thread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        thread = null;

    }

    public void resume(){
        CanDraw = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I test your code in sdk 15  and it works fine .only difference is in onCreat method . I don't  use PersistableBundle

Comment: Thank you! I have removed PersistableBundle and it's work. I have no idea what the heck is PersistableBundle, maybe it's because I am using Android studio 2.1.2 with sdk 24